# Change BuildAction to None in VSIX

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, vsix, buildaction

So I am currently working on an extension and I want to change the Build Action of a specific `ProjectItem` to `None`.

#### What I tried

I noticed that the `ProjectItem` had a `Properties` property which contains the following `KeyValuePair` wher the key is `BuildAction`. Therefor I tried to set its Value to `prjBuildActionNone` which should be the correct value for it.

Anyway, when I hit Play and the code runs and I set a breakpoint on this very line:

`prop.Value = "prjBuildActionNone"`

The Debugger will never return to the line below and that is it.

Is there anything I am doing wrong with this approach or is this the totally wrong direction and the `Properties` property is for read-only purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value should be a member of the [`prjBuildAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/vslangproj.prjbuildaction) enumeration, e.g. `prjBuildAction.prjBuildActionNone`.

Execution is not reaching the next line because the incorrect type is causing an exception.